# send message to connected computer when IP obtain from DHCP Server

Tags: ubuntu, windows, networking, dhcp, server-message-block

If a computer running Windows gets a IP address from DHCP Server, how could I send a message to that computer. Say DHCP Server running from Ubuntu Server. I am guessing through SMBClient? Or is this not possible with out creating and distributing a program to the connected computer?

Here's a example of what I am talking about.

```
Computer1, connects to Wireless SSID successfully.
Computer1, obtains IP address from DHCPServer (Ubuntu Server).
Ubuntu Server, sends Computer 1 message upon obtaining IP address from DHCP Server.
Computer1, see message "You have successfully joined my network".
```

This is all I am looking for. I would think a script would take care of this on the Ubuntu Server. The script would have to include smbclient message command and knowing when a IP was obtained by the DHCP Server, correct?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux dhcpd can be configured to execute a script on significant events. There is a similar question at [Executing a script when DHCPD give an IP](https://superuser.com/questions/211411/executing-a-script-when-dhcpd-give-an-ip).

Windows supports a deprecated Messenger service that can receive such messages, but this has been [disabled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Messenger_service) by default since Windows XP Service Pack 2.

Your experience with integration to an IM platform like Windows Messenger will vary with the penetration of this application in your user environment.